# Mixpanel error - Painel de execução do Snippet está com erro

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

Não sei se é com todo mundo, mas no Chrome tenho recebido esse mensagem de erro no Snippet das Respostas e Perguntas. Será que é algum problema com versão de Java ou versão do Browser ou está acontecendo com todos?

> **Error:** Mixpanel error: "mixpanel" object not initialized. Ensure you are using the latest version of the Mixpanel JS Library along with the snippet we provide.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Comigo não acontece. Pode ser conflito com alguma extensão que você tem no browser.

Comment: Pra mim o problema era numa extensão chamada [Page Ruler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn).

Comment: @LINQ Era ela mesmo, eu desativei e resolveu, mas como a resposta do Guilherme da pra manter o plugin ativo e resolver o problema ao mesmo temo. O estranho é que eu não tinha esse erro, mas de um dia para o outro isso começou não sei pq... Deve ter sido uma "atualização maliciosa" do desenvolvedor do plugin ou sei lá.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta do [**SOen**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48640279/1518921) possivelmente é o problema pode ser causado pela extensão [**Page Ruler**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-ruler/jlpkojjdgbllmedoapgfodplfhcbnbpn?hl=nl) que usa isto:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://cdn.mxpnl.com/libs/mixpanel-2-latest.min.js"></script>
```

E conforme [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668589/1518921) para evitar o problema pode experimentar desabilitar o <kbd>Send Anonymous Usage Statistics</kbd>

> [image: Send Anonymous Usage Statistics]

Instalei o add-on criei um stack-snippet e o erro não ocorreu, mas quando **ativei** o <kbd>Send Anonymous Usage Statistics</kbd> o erro ocorreu, veja:

[image: erro]

Comment: Valeu meu jovem! "Bug" resolvido, obrigado!